# Bringing a subview in a UITableViewCell to front

Tags: uitableview

I added a bunch of `UILabel` views to a `UITableViewCell`'s `contentView`, some of which may overlap. On tapping any of the labels, I want to trigger some actions. Also, I want to bring up the tapped label to the top.

Using a UITapGestureRecognizer on the labels, I can figure out which one is tapped and perform the actions. But bringing the tapped and overlapped label to the front does not work. This is what I am trying:

```
UILabel *foundLabel = ....; // find the label
for (UITableViewCell *acell in theTable.visibleCells) {
    UIView *cellContentView = acell.contentView;
    if ([cellContentView.subviews containsObject:foundLabel]) {
        [cellContentView bringSubviewToFront:foundLabel];
        NSLog(@"should bring to front...");
    }
}
```

I do get the `NSLog` output above, so I know that the `bringSubviewToFront` is being called on the appropriate cell's `contentView`. But no change in the subview layout order.

Ideas?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? Would be interested to know as I'm having a similar problem.

Answer (score 18):

One thing to explore is zposition on the uitablviewcell's layer.

This successfully put on tableviewcell in front of another for me:

```
    cell1.layer.zPosition=3 ;//above

    cell2.layer.zPosition=2 ;//below
```

Answer (score 3):

`bringSubviewToFront:` didn't work for me either

Try `insertSubview:belowSubview:` where the latter subview is a super view such as tab bar, nav bar, table view.

Comment: NOTE: insertSubview does not create extra UIView replicas on subsequent calls.